# Definition of denseness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The set of  rationals in $(0,1)$ are dense.

I am confused by its definition.

Some of my friends says that $A$ is dense in $X$ if closure of $A$ is $X$

and  some say

That $A$ and $B$ are subset of reals and $A$ is subset of $B$. Then $A$ is dense in $B$ if $B$ is contained in closure of $A$.
Please anyone explain  with examples

Comment: Normally "$A$ is dense in $X$" means that $A\subset X$, $X$ is a topological space, and $A$ intersects all open sets of the topology of $X$. So, when you take the closure of $A$ it is all of $X$.

Comment: Both are clearly equivalent.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If A is dense in  B then can I say that between two elements of B there is always a element  of A?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a topological space (e.g. any subset of $\mathbb{R}$).  The usual definition of a subset $A \subseteq X$ being dense in $X$ is that the closure of $A$ in $X$ is $X$.

The thing is that "closure" is a relative term: it depends on what space you are thinking about.  If you have $A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the closure of $A$ in $B$ is in general not the same thing as the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, if $B = (0,1)$, and $A = (0,\frac{1}{2})$, the closure of $A$ in $B$ is $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$, while the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Here is how the two different notions of closure are related: the closure of $A$ in $B$ is equal to $\overline{A} \cap B$, where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, to say that $A$ is dense in $B$, i.e. the closure of $A$ in $B$ is equal to $B$, is to say that $B = \overline{A} \cap B$.  But this last equation is the same thing as saying that $B \subseteq \overline{A}$.

Comment: Sir  If A is dense in  B then can I say that between two elements of B there is always a element  of A?

Comment: No, for example let $B = (0,1] \cup [2,3)$, and $A$ the dense set $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$.  There are no element $x \in A$ satisfying $2 \leq x \leq 3$.

Comment: a set A  is always dense in closure of A  if closure of A is non empty . Am I right ?

Comment: Empty or not, $A$ is always dense in $\overline{A}$ (if $A = \emptyset$, then $\overline{A} = \emptyset$ as well)

Answer (score 0):

The general definition: if $X$ is a space, $D \subseteq X$ is dense iff $\operatorname{cl}_X(D) = X$, where $\operatorname{cl}_X$ denotes the closure in $X$. This is the first definition that you name.

If $B \subseteq X$ has the subspace topology (so we consider $B$ as topological space in its own right, in the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_B = \{O \cap B: O \in \mathcal{T}_X\}$), then for any subset $A$ of $B$, the definition of subspace topology implies the standard fact relating closures in $B$ to the ones in $X$:

$$\operatorname{cl}_B(A) = \operatorname{cl}_X(A) \cap B$$

So $A$ is dense in the space $B$ means (using the general definition for the space $B$) that $\operatorname{cl}_B(A) = B$ so 
$\operatorname{cl}_X(A) \cap B = B$, which means exactly that $B \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_X(A)$. This is exactly the second definition you mention. 
So that one is the general definition applied $B$ as a space its own right.

The above applies to all spaces (not just subsets of the reals). Your original example $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$, all rationals in $(0,1)$ is dense in $(0,1)$ (or $[0,1]$ as well) as $\operatorname{cl}_{\mathbb{R}}(A) = [0,1]$.